# Pass IDs from apex controller to an apex batch class

Tags: apex, batch, controller, parameters

Can I pass IDs from apex controller to apex batch class?

Can someone please show me some examples? Can't find in google search.
I need just a reverse of below link.
https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/?id=906F000000096KeIAI

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For example, you have:

1. **Base** (Apex Class) and a variable **storeID** (where you stored the ID/s)
2. **Group** (Batch Class) and a variable **passedID**

**Base**

inside the method calling the batch

```
Group grp = new Group(storeID);
Database.executeBatch(grp);
```

**Group**

```
public Group(*variable type* storeID)
{
passedID = storeID;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can create variable in you batch class something like " `global List<Id> currentId ;"` and from your main class set the value of this variable using class instance and then use this variable in your batch class. It works fine for you.
Here is a example

```
public class batchclass implements Database.Batchable<sObject>{

global List<Id> currentId ;

// Start Method
        global Database.QueryLocator start(Database.BatchableContext BC){

                return Database.getQueryLocator('SELECT Id,Name FROM Opportunity WHERE Id in :currentId and Type in : oppTypes ');
        }
}
```

and your main class

```
public class mainclass { 
public void somemethod() {
batchclass bat = new batchclass ();
bat.currentId =  opptyId ;
database.executeBatch(bat,2) ;
}

}
```

Comment: Can you please show me an example ? I am not getting it . Sorry!

Comment: @SFDC_Learner update my answer.